# Docker commit and save with Rancher API

Tags: api, docker, save, commit, rancher

Is it possible to `docker commit` and `docker save` a container via the Rancher API? I could not find any resources about this.

Comment: In general this isn't a best practice; it's almost always better to describe your changes in a Dockerfile, commit it to source control, and `docker build` it when you need to.  If you can set up a Docker registry server or use a cloud-hosted server, that's also much better than manually `docker save`ing images.

Comment: Yes, it is not a good practice, but I would still like to know whether it is actually possible through the Rancher API